# How can I print a doubly-linked list?

Tags: c, list, printing, doubly-linked-list

I wrote a program that creates a list from a sorted array, but somehow my print function does not work. Does anybody know what the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


typedef struct node{struct node *prev; int data; struct node *next;} node;
node *head;

void insertion_at_beginning();
void insertion_at_end();
void bubble_sort();
void print_list();
node* array_to_list();


int main()
{
    srand((long) time(NULL));
    int data[200];

    node *head = NULL;

    for (int i=0;i<200;i++){
        data[i] = rand() % (49 + 1 - 0) + 0;
    }

    bubble_sort(data, 200);

    head = array_to_list(data, 200);
    print_list(head, "LIST");

    return 0;
}

void insertion_at_beginning(int d)
{
   struct node *ptr;

   ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   if(ptr == NULL)
   {
       printf("\no v e r f l o w");


   if(head==NULL)
   {
       ptr -> next = NULL;
       ptr -> prev = NULL;
       ptr -> data = d;
       head = ptr;
   }
   else
   {
       ptr -> data = d;
       ptr -> prev = NULL;
       ptr -> next = head;
       head -> prev = ptr;
       head = ptr;
   }
}
}

void insertion_at_end(int f)
{
   struct node *ptr, *temp;

   ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   if(ptr == NULL)
   {
       printf("\no v e r f l o w");
   }

       ptr -> data = f;
       if(head == NULL)
       {
           ptr -> next = NULL;
           ptr -> prev = NULL;
           head = ptr;
       }
       else
       {
          temp = head;
          while(temp -> next != NULL)
          {
              temp = temp -> next;
          }
          temp -> next = ptr;
          ptr -> prev = temp;
          ptr -> next = NULL;
          }

       }

node* array_to_list(int d[], int size)
{
    insertion_at_beginning(d[0]);
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        insertion_at_beginning(d[i]);
    }
    return head;
}

void bubble_sort(int array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++)
          {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < size - i - 1; j++)
            {
              if (array[j] < array[j+1])
              {
                  int temp = array[j];
                  array[j] = array[j+1];
                  array[j+1] = temp;
              }
            }
          }
}

void print_list(node *h, char *title)
{
    printf("%s\n\n", title);
    while (h != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d : ", h -> data);
        h = h -> next;
        printf("%d : ", h -> data);
        h = h -> next;
        printf("%d : ", h -> data);
        h = h -> next;
        printf("%d : ", h -> data);
        h = h -> next;
        printf("%d : ", h -> data);
        h = h -> next;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

So with this last function I did manage printing a singly-linked list, and I thought that it should work the same way with a doubly linked list. But somehow it does not print anything except the title "LIST".

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Having a global and local variables with the same name (ie `head`) is asking for trouble BTW

Comment: Build with extra warnings enabled, and treat them as errors. Always include arguments in your function forward declarations!

Comment: Your code does not compile: `node* head = insertion_at_beginning` is a void function. Please [edit] and paste your _actual_ code.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I am a beginner, so sorry if the code is not efficiently documented or if there are some dumb mistakes.

Comment: insertion_at_beginning has all of its code inide the error case

Comment: Also the `print_list` looks like total nonsense. You have `printf("%d : ", h->data); h = h->next;` 5 times, it should be there only once.

Comment: @stark thanks that solved the problem. After removing `if(ptr == NULL)` ... the list gets printed now.

Comment: @emircg02 The code you posted here does not compile and therefore it cannot run. There is something fishy with your question, you probably posted the wrong code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky well i edited the code and now the code runs. And I printed it 5 times because I wanted to have the list being printed in rows of 5. And sry for my English its not my first language.

Comment: @emircg02  _"And I printed it 5 times because I wanted to have the list being printed in rows of 5_" this cannot work. Imagine what happens if your list contains, say 2 elements. Try with `for (int i=0;i<3;i++)` in `main` and see what happens

Comment: @emircg02 don't correct the code you were asking questions about. It makes existing comments/answers invalid. I rolled back.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Compiler warnings and debugging is not obvious for beginners, that could be the main problem.

Comment: *"don't correct the code you were asking questions about"* @Jabberwocky I think it's okay to edit before answer is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in void insertion_at_beginning(int d)

```
   if(ptr == NULL)
   {
       printf("\no v e r f l o w");
                                        <<<< NO EXIT BRACKET

   if(head==NULL)
   {
       ptr -> next = NULL;
       ptr -> prev = NULL;
       ptr -> data = d;
       head = ptr;
   }
   else
   {
       ptr -> data = d;
       ptr -> prev = NULL;
       ptr -> next = head;
       head -> prev = ptr;
       head = ptr;
   }
}
```

So your code does nothing unless malloc returns NULL.
Learning lesson : Formating your code (with a tool like clang-tidy) can save you a red-face.